# Unable to interact with Ubuntu in VirtualBox after unlock screen

Tags: virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox *(7.0.8 r156879 (Qt5.15.2))* machine with Ubuntu *22.04.2 LTS*.
Usually it works without any issue when I start it. But after several minutes of inactivity when VM system locks out, I enter my password, it unlocks the system, shows previously opened windows and after that I cannot do anything inside the VM: it looks completely ok (the cursor blinks, etc.), but my mouse and keyboard do not interact with the system, I must turn it off completely and start it over in order to continue working.

Simply locking it myself (throughout menu) works ok.

Do you know if there is any issue with VB - Ubuntu setup with such behavior?

I have turned off locking out they system, but for some reason it did not help. The workaround is just keep working with the system and not leave it more then the lock time but sometimes it's hard.

There are similar questions with the system freezing, but it's not the same situation as the system seems not frozen but just not react to mouse and keyboard.